# Compare old and new values on post update

Tags: php, wordpress

I can use **update_post_meta** hook to get old value before update and **updated_post_meta** to get new value after update.
How can I compare old value and new value in one method?

Comment: `https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/301247` This might help you